# How to Dynamodb send message to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I have a table in AWS Dynamodb and i need send message to AWS SQS when a new item is created. 
So i want my Dynamodb to be triggered at that exact moment when created new item, a message for the AWS SQS.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by using [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) to trigger a Lambda function that then writes to an SQS queue.